# Gradient effect for listing screen in jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on MObile app,i have listing screen for that i have navbar (sunday, monday, tuesday), and i assigned 3 diffetent colous to navbar.
what i need is if i click on sunday that particular (slightly-gradient) color should appear for that particluar listing screen. (because i want to differentiate between the 3 listing screens based on colours). Thanks in advance .
My current code is

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
<h1>Index</h1>
 </div>
 <form id="form1" >
  <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#sunday" class="sunday"  data-ajax="false" >sunday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#monday" class="monday" data-ajax="false" >monday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tuesday" class="tuesday" data-ajax="false" >tuesday</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="ui-filterable" >
    <input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search" placeholder="Search ">
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" id="sunday">
    <div class="content-primary" >
      <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-icon="false">
        <li class="custom">
          <h3><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;" >Row1</a></h3>
          <p class="topic"><strong>sub</strong></p>
          <p>date</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside"> <span> <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" ></a> </span></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;">Row2</a></h3>
          <p class="topic"><strong>sub </strong></p>
          <p>date</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside"> <span> <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" ></a> </span></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div data-role="content" id="monday">
    <div class="content-primary" >
      <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-icon="false">
        <li>
          <h3><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;">Row1</a></h3>
          <p class="topic"><strong>sub</strong></p>
          <p>date</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside"> <span><a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"  data-transition="pop"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" ></a></span> </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;">Row2</a></h3>
          <p class="topic"><strong>sub</strong></p>
          <p>date</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside"> <span><a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"  data-transition="pop"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" ></a></span> </p>
          </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" id="tuesday">
    <div class="content-primary" >
      <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-icon="false">
        <li>
          <h3><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;font-weight:normal;">Row1</a></h3>
          <p class="topic">sub</p>
          <p>date</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside"> <span> <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"  data-transition="pop"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" ></a></span> 
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;font-weight:normal;">Row2</a></h3>
          <p class="topic">sub</p>
          <p>date</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside"> <span> <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"  data-transition="pop"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" ></a></span> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </form>
   </div>
   **css**
   .sunday{
background: #f58f8f !important;}
    .monday{
background: #a3c9e9 !important;}
    .tuesday{
background: #f6d777 !important;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some Click functions and the addClass option. Also add some classes for you li tags so the addclass knows where to add the class to change the colors.

```
  $(".sunday").click(function() { 
    $(".custom").addClass("sunday"); 
  });

  $(".monday").click(function() { 
    $(".customb").addClass("monday"); 
  });

 $(".tuesday").click(function() { 
    $(".customc").addClass("tuesday"); 
  });
```

I made a demo for you

http://jsfiddle.net/Mwaw5/

Comment: Just go to the link below and choose a gradient color you like, and  copy the code from the right and create some css classes for them. Then change the the addclac(Sunday, Monday, Tuesday) to reflect the new classes with gradients you just created. Thats it. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/